# DocuSign attaching a document to an envelope

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I was wondering if it was possible to attach a document or documents to an envelope when sending envelopes via SOAP API? I have used the api to create an Attachment object and added the bytes but when I attach to the envelope the status envelope attachments comes back as null and when I look at the docusign email there is no attachment( I'm assuming is due to the fact that attachment returns as null in the status, but when I debug it the attachment is clearly there. Can a sender attach documents to an envelope?

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(){
   Data = "bytes",
   Label = "name",
   Type = "Document"
};
newTemplate.Envelope.EnvelopeAttachment = new Attachment[] { attachment };
```

Finally I attach the attachment to the envelope and send.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **EnvelopeAttachment** property of the **Envelope** object in the SOAP API merely exists as a way for an integrated application to "pass along" another file with an Envelope during the Create Envelope process, such that this file will be associated with the Envelope from that point forward and the integrated application can access it in the future via API if necessary.  Files supplied in this manner (i.e., using the **EnvelopeAttachment** property) will never be visible within the DocuSign UI, or to the recipients of the Envelope in the Envelope itself -- the only way to access them is via the API.

If you merely need to add another file to the Envelope that all recipients will see in the Envelope but that no recipients are required to sign, etc., then you should add that file to the Envelope in the same way that you add all other files to the Envelope (i.e., using **Documents** property of the **Envelope** object) and just don't specify any Tabs for that document.